# Index matrix but return a list of lists Pytorch

Tags: python, performance, indexing, pytorch

I have a 2-dimensional tensor and I would like to index it so that the result is a list of lists. For example:

```
R = torch.tensor([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
mask = torch.tensor([[1,0,0],[1,1,1]], dtype=torch.bool)
output = R[mask]
```

This makes `output` as `tensor([1, 4, 5, 6])`. However, I would like to have `[[1], [4,5,6]]` or `[tensor(1), tensor([4,5,6])]`.

I now that it could be done with a loop and ussing `.append()`. However, I would like to avoid the use of any loop to make it faster if `R` and `mask` are very big.

Is there any way to do that in Python without any loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using PyTorch's indexing and broadcasting:

```
output = R[mask].split([mask[i].sum() for i in range(mask.shape[0])])
```

This splits the resulting tensor based on `True` values in each row of the mask, which gives a list of tensors where each element corresponds to a row of the original tensor.
The `.split()` method returns a tuple of tensors, so you can cast each element of the tuple to a list or a tensor as follows:

```
output = [tensor.tolist() for tensor in output]
```

This will give a list of lists, wherein each sublist corresponds to a row of the original tensor with the `False` values removed.

Comment: You can even rewrite to `R[mask].split([o.sum() for o in mask])` or alternatively `R[mask].split(list(mask.sum(1)))`.